# Deskew bounding box

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, bounding-box

I am working on an application to detect a card in an image and I am doing so successfully however sometimes the card is not straight, it may have a slight skew.

```
Mat card;
card = src(bounding_box);
```

I feel that the best way might be to find the skew of the bounding box before hand and then rotate the extracted image to correct the skew.

Here is an example of a card being found:

[image]

Not all cards have a substantial amount of skew, such as the example but in some cases there is quite a bit of skew.

How can I find the bounding box's skew angle, and then rotate the extracted image? Right now I am just doing this to extract the rect out of the image

Comment: as far as I see, the bounding box is axis aligned and so it has no skew?!? Instead I guess your picture of the card has skew and you want to extract the skewed bounding box to fit the card?!?

Comment: Try using minAreaRect instead of bounding box. It'll give you the rotation angle.

Answer (score 0):

By eroding and boxing the resulting points, you can calculate the angle:

```
double deskew(const char* filename)
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filename, 0);

    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 3));
    cv::erode(img, img, element);

    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();

    for (; it != end; ++it)
       if (*it)
          points.push_back(it.pos());

    cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

    double angle = box.angle;
    if (angle < -45.)
       angle += 90.;

    return angle;
}
```

[OpenCV Bouding Box & Skew Angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/)

Then you can deskew with:

```
void deskew(cv::Mat img, double angle)
{
  cv::bitwise_not(img, img);

  std::vector<cv::Point> points;
  cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
  cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
      points.push_back(it.pos());

  cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

  cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, angle, 1);

  cv::Mat rotated;
  cv::warpAffine(img, rotated, rot_mat, img.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
}
```

[OpenCV Rotating/Deskewing](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code faster by replacing this:

```
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
      points.push_back(it.pos());`
```

...with this:

```
points.push_back(cv::Point(0,0));
points.push_back(cv::Point(img.rows,0));
points.push_back(cv::Point(img.rows,img.cols));
points.push_back(cv::Point(0,img.cols));
```

You just need the further points, not all of them inside.

Comment: Wouldn't this only sample the 4 corners of the image itself? How would that help here? Sorry if I'm lost; I'm learning from examples here :)